# Remove data less than a certain number, use remaining information to create a new row to make a bar plot that adds up to 100%

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am trying to create a bar graph for microbiome data with multiple samples I want to do the following: 
1) Remove phylum that are less than 1% 
2) Create another row (Other Prokaryotes) in the data.frame for each site that contains the result of 1 - the remaining phylums in each site 
3) make a bar graph that actually adds up to 100%

I have already tried the following code

```
library(phyloseq)
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)

# get abundance in %
phy <- transform_sample_counts(HCSData, function(x) 100*x/sum(x))

# agglomerate taxa
glom <- tax_glom(phy, taxrank = 'Phylum')

# create dataframe from phyloseq object
dat <- psmelt(glom)

# convert Phylum to a character vector from a factor because R
dat$Phylum <- as.character(dat$Phylum)

# group dataframe by Phylum, calculate median rel. abundance
medians <- ddply(dat, ~Phylum, function(x) c(median=median(x$Abundance)))

# find Phyla whose rel. abund. is less than 1%
Other <- medians[medians$median <= 1,]$Phylum

# change their name to "Other Prokaryotes"
dat[dat$Phylum %in% Other,]$Phylum <- 'Other Prokaryotes'

# plot the data
spatial_plot <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Sample, y=Abundance, fill=Phylum)) 
spatial_plot + geom_bar(aes(), stat="identity", position="stack")
```

Basic data.frame format is an abundance associated with a phylum, with multiple phylum associated with each site

More Meta tables exist but I removed them for shortness sake

dput(head(dat, 5))

```
structure(list(OTU = c("0dc32a3ede2e7900d7c68995d0c7932e", "0dc32a3ede2e7900d7c68995d0c7932e", 
"0dc32a3ede2e7900d7c68995d0c7932e", "0dc32a3ede2e7900d7c68995d0c7932e", 
"0dc32a3ede2e7900d7c68995d0c7932e"), Sample = c("FPW17-2", "FPD18", 
"FPW17-3", "HTW17-2", "HTW17-1"), Abundance = c(48.1361496328729, 
46.5229073579116, 44.8077533875185, 44.5057689091552, 44.2731275877354
), sampleid = c(14, 62, 26, 20, 8), X. = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AbbSeason = c("W", 
"D", "W", "W", "W"), AbbSeasonAbbYear = c("W17", "D18", "W17", 
"W17", "W17"), AbbSite = c("FP", "FP", "FP", "HT", "HT"), AbbSiteAbbSeasonAbbYear = c("FPW17-2", 
"FPD18", "FPW17-3", "HTW17-2", "HTW17-1"), AbbSiteMonth = c("FP-September", 
"FP-April", "FP-October", "HT-September", "HT-August"), Kingdom = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("D_0__Archaea", "D_0__Bacteria"
    ), class = "factor"), Phylum = c("D_1__Proteobacteria", "D_1__Proteobacteria", 
    "D_1__Proteobacteria", "D_1__Proteobacteria", "D_1__Proteobacteria"
    )), row.names = c(69L, 67L, 86L, 80L, 83L), class = "data.frame")
```

Sample Abundance Phylum              Season 
1       50        Proteobacteria     Wet 
1       20        Firmicutes         Wet 
2       40        Proteobacteria     Dry 
2       30        Firmicutes         Dry 
etc... (sorry could not figure out with ?help how to create table)

But the rows do not add up to 100% in the graph. I figure this is more of a basic r question than a phyloseq question which is why I am here

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of `dat` using `dput(head(dat, x))`? Replace `x` with the number of rows necessary to generate a representative data set.

Comment: @Mako212 I made the edit you asked for, thanks for assistance.

Comment: Isn't the problem that you normalize before you remove the less abundant pylums? You'll need to normalize again after removal.

Comment: Okay thanks @ekstroem , I used your comment to make some code to fix it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
##Create table ready for making stacked bar graph for Phylums <1%##
# get abundance in %
phy <- transform_sample_counts(data, function(x) 100*x/sum(x))
# agglomerate taxa
glom <- tax_glom(phy, taxrank = 'Phylum')
# create dataframe from phyloseq object
dat <- psmelt(glom)
# convert Phylum to a character vector from a factor because R
dat$Phylum <- as.character(dat$Phylum)
# group dataframe by Phylum, calculate median rel. abundance
medians <- ddply(dat, ~Phylum, function(x) c(median=median(x$Abundance)))
# find Phyla whose rel. abund. is less than 1%
Other <- medians[medians$median <= 1,]$Phylum
# change their name to "Other Prokaryotes"
dat[dat$Phylum %in% Other,]$Phylum <- 'Other Prokaryotes'
#remove all Phylums labeled Other Prokaryotes
dat <-dat[!dat$Phylum=="Other Prokaryotes",]
#remove unncessary columns
dat <- subset(dat, select=c(Sample, Abundance, Phylum))
#Arrange by Abundance
dat <- arrange(dat, Abundance)
#Create a table that is the leftover Prokaryotes
Abundance <- ddply(dat, ~Sample, function(x) c(Abundance=100-sum(x$Abundance)))
#Add a column labeling the leftover Prokaryotes
Abundance$Phylum<- "Other Prokaryotes"
#combine with original table
OnePhylumdatAb <- rbind(dat, Abundance)
```

Comment: Maybe a round about way of doing it but it works, makes bar graphs that add up to 100% with Other Prokaryotes having phylums <1%